# Detecting text change in a empty textbox

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Okay so I have this code so far:

```
    final EditText textBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textBox1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                avalue = (Integer.parseInt(textBox1.getText().toString()));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Works " + avalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                UpdateMain();
            } finally {
                return;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

This works pretty fine but I still want the run the updater when you empty the textbox or remove all characters in the textbox because by default no number equals 1.

Comment: afterTextChanged()  if s.length() == 0 textBox1.removeOnTextChangedListener(this); textBox1.setText("1"); textBox1.addOnTextChangedListener(this); but need more logic for after its set to 1. On a mobile so that's best I can do for now

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
final EditText textBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
textBox1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try {
            avalue = 0;
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                avalue = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Works " + avalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            UpdateMain();
        } finally {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Notes:

- I decided to put the logic in `afterTextChanged()`, but you can put it back in `onTextChanged()` if that is more appropriate.
- Also, this logic sets `avalue` to 0 if the box is empty. You can change this logic, as appropriate.